# Why do I get 0 rows when I join multiple table with a personal id?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table whose matching type of clothes and the name of the model for one owner. The table is given by a software I work with, I can't change the design of my model.

The owner of this wardrobe is Paul who has `poa` as a personal ID

| ID | owner_id | cid | Name | Type | Date_own_from | Date_own_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | poa | sho-1 | The dragon | Shoes | 01-01-2021 | 01-10-2021 |
| 2 | poa | shi-1 | SimpleT | Shirt | 01-01-2021 | 31-12-2099 |
| 3 | poa | so-21 | White model | Sockets | 01-01-2021 | 31-12-2099 |
| 4 | poa | sho-3 | Snake speed 3 | Shoes | 01-10-2021 | 31-12-2099 |

An Owner can only own **one pair of each** type of clothes. If `Date_own_to` is `31-12-2099` it means that the owner didn't bring the clothe back.

Each type correspond of one table which has more information about the product

Here is an example for Shoes :

| ID | Clothes_ID | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sho-1 | 42 |

Here is for Shirts :

| ID | Clothes_ID | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | shi-1 | M |

And for Sockets :

| ID | Clothes_ID | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | so-21 | M |

What I'm trying to do is to list every clothes for each person like this :

| ID | Owner | Shoes | Shirt | Sockets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | poa | SnakeSpeed | SimpleT | White model |

So I tried to do this :

```
SELECT * FROM wardrobe w
JOIN shoes sho 
 on sho.clothes_id = w.cid 
where owner_id = 'poa'
```

With this request I got this :

| ID | Owner | Shoes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | poa | SnakeSpeed |

But now when I try to join an other table table with this request

```
SELECT * FROM wardrobe w
JOIN shoes sho 
 on sho.clothes_id = w.cid 
JOIN shirt shi
 on shi.clothes_id = w.cid
where owner_id = 'poa'
```

And the result of this is 0 rows.

I don't know how to properly join the values.

What I am doing wrong?

**Multiple Rows**

Since I only have one t-shirt owned for one period. If I want to look for the clothes owned by a person for a given period I would like to do something like this :

`date_own_from = '01-01-2021' and date_own_to = '31-12-2021'`

So the desired results would be :

| ID | Name | Shoes | Shirt | Sockets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paul | SnakeSpeed | SimpleT | White model |
| 2 | Paul | The Dragon | SimpleT | White model |

A row 2 differents shoes owned during the year with the Shirt and the Socket owned when the persons owned the shoes.

Comment: Try using LEFT JOIN.  Ordinary JOIN suppresses rows that don't match the ON condition.

Comment: Can you show us the desired result?

Comment: You appear to be missing sample data for the table `Shirt`. I thought it was the 3rd table, but that is missing the column `clothes_id`.

Comment: @O.Jones I already try this. But I want every clothes is supposed to match the condition.

Comment: @ShabbirHussain The desired result is the fifth table.

Comment: I think the biggest issue here is your design is problematic. You have three identical tables for shoes, shirts and sockets. That sounds like a single fact table to me with a column for the type.

Comment: @SeanLange I know the design isn't good. But I got those value from a Software and they designed their database like this.

Comment: In response to "WHY" - because your wardrobe data is distributed between many rows. You should start with pivoting wardrobe table, creating single row/reocrd for single person, containing IDs for different tables; then you can join other tables to corresponding IDs. Note that adding any new category of clothing requires to rewrite all queries - but as you can't change database design, you have to live with that.

Comment: @Arvo Thank you for your answer. I understand now the problem. Can you show me a simple example of your solution with my simplified dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the poor design you have to work with you have a struggle here.

Here is sample data and ddl in case anybody wants to play along.

```
create table Wardrobe
(
    ID int
    , owner_id varchar(10)
    , cid varchar(10)
    , Name varchar(20)
    , Type varchar(10)
)

insert Wardrobe
select 1, 'poa', 'sho-1', 'SnakeSpeed', 'Shoes' union all
select 2, 'poa', 'shi-1', 'SimpleT', 'Shirt' union all
select 3, 'poa', 'so-21', 'White model', 'Sockets'

insert Wardrobe
select 4, 'poa', 'so-22', 'green', 'Sockets'

create table Shoes
(
    ID int
    , Clothes_ID varchar(10)
    , Size varchar(10)
)

insert Shoes
select 1, 'sho-1', '42'

create table Shirts
(
    ID int
    , Clothes_ID varchar(10)
    , Size varchar(10)
)

insert Shirts
select 1, 'shi-1', 'M'

create table Sockets
(
    ID int
    , Clothes_ID varchar(10)
    , Size varchar(10)
)

insert Sockets
select 2, 'so-22', 'M'
```

There are probably some other ways to deal with this. But this example will work even if they a single person has only two shoes and a single shirt with no sockets. I started by isolating each set of rows using some ctes and row_number. Then munge them back together with some conditional aggregation.

```
declare @Owner varchar(10) = 'poa';

with cteShoes as
(
    select w.ID
        , w.owner_id
        , w.Name
        , sho.Size
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by w.Name)
    from Wardrobe w     
    join Shoes sho on sho.Clothes_ID = w.cid and w.Type = 'Shoes'
    where w.owner_id = @Owner
)
, cteShirts as
(
    select w.ID
        , w.owner_id
        , w.Name
        , shi.Size
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by w.Name)
    from Wardrobe w 
    join Shirts shi on shi.Clothes_ID = w.cid and w.Type = 'Shirt'
    where w.owner_id = @Owner
)
, cteSockets as
(
    select w.ID
        , w.owner_id
        , w.Name
        , soc.Size
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by w.Name)
    from Wardrobe w 
    join Sockets soc on soc.Clothes_ID = w.cid and w.Type = 'Sockets'
    where w.owner_id = @Owner
)

select Owner = coalesce(sho.owner_id, shi.owner_id, soc.owner_id)
    , Shoes = max(case when sho.RowNum is not null then sho.Name end)
    , ShoesSize = max(case when sho.RowNum is not null then sho.Size end)
    , Shirt = max(case when shi.RowNum is not null then shi.Name end)
    , ShirtSize = max(case when shi.RowNum is not null then shi.Size end)
    , Sockets = max(case when soc.RowNum is not null then soc.Name end)
    , SocketsSize = max(case when soc.RowNum is not null then soc.Size end)
from cteShoes sho
full outer join cteShirts shi on shi.RowNum = sho.RowNum
full outer join cteSockets soc on soc.RowNum = sho.RowNum
group by coalesce(sho.ID, shi.ID, soc.ID)
    , coalesce(sho.owner_id, shi.owner_id, soc.owner_id)
```

Comment: Ok I see. Thank you very much. I had struggle to work with this design but sadly I can't change it. I'll try tomorrow if this works but I think it will. I just forgot to say that a person can only own one pair of each, so I'll try your solution without the multiple-owning case!

Comment: This should work just the same if they only own a single set of each item. The only real difference would be that you don't need to utilize row_number and could eliminate the ctes.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought. I edited my question if you wanna check ! The design of this software isn't good but I have to deal with it. I'll try tomorrow and comeback If I have any trouble. Thank you

Comment: Can you show me how can I deal with the multiple rows that I edited in my question with the date type and the owners ? I have some struggle with that

Comment: Just add the date predicates to the three ctes.

Comment: why row_number and max -- with row number you can just add `and rownum = 1`  to each join

Answer (score 1):

Use left joins since there are no shirts for this user

```
SELECT w.*, shoes.*, shirt.*
FROM (SELECT distinct cid, owner_id FROM wardrobe) w
LEFT JOIN (SELECT cid, clothes_id
           FROM wardrobe WHERE type ='Shoes') shoelink ON shoelink.cid = w.cid
LEFT JOIN shoes sho on sho.clothes_id = shoelink.cid 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT cid, clothes_id
           FROM wardrobe WHERE type ='Shirt') shirtlink ON shirtlink.cid = w.cid
LEFT JOIN shirt shi on shi.clothes_id = shirtlink.cid
where w.owner_id = 'poa'
```

Comment: There is a shirt for this user. The "SimpleT" model

Comment: This is only part of the solution. They want a single result set with columns for each type. I would assume they rows where most of the details are null.

Comment: @SeanLange -- not sure what that has to do with your question -- the answer to your question is to use left join.

Comment: @Hogan - this isn't my question I was pointing out that they don't want three rows in the result set. They want a single row. Probably easiest to use conditional aggregation. ;)

Comment: I see... give me a second to write that for you.

Comment: @SeanLange -- that is how I would do it -- you can also do it with a group by and max

Comment: @Hogan in your solution, there's an error `Ambiguous column name 'owner_id'`. I think it's because you didn't specified which `owner_id` it is since there's 3 differents `wardrobe` table

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you need to join any table because they are not adding anything to your results - unless you have oversimplified.

Based on your results this will do.

But, if an owner has more than one pair of shoes etc, you need to tell us what you want to see in your results.

```
SELECT
  owner_id AS owner,
  MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'shoes' THEN name END) AS shoes,
  MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'shirt' THEN name END) AS shirt,
  MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'sockets' THEN name END) AS sockets
FROM w
GROUP BY owner_id
```

Comment: There's only one pair for one person but the person can change a t-shirt per example with a `date_owner_from` and `date_owner_to`. So the case where it can display multiple rows its when I do a `between` two dates. So If the owner had 2 different t-shirt in the specified period then I should display 2 rows (one for each t-shirt) and the clothes that were owned in this period. I can show you an example if you want.

Comment: Please do show an example and any other possibilities with the data.....its better for all of us if we know everything at the start rather than a constant drip feed.

Comment: I edited my question if you wanna see how I want to deal with multiple rows. And I need to join the values because yes, I have oversimplified my request but I want to display more values than came from the table.